# What could allow Azure AD application access without sign-out if local state is cleared?

Tags: azure-active-directory

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-openid-connect-code#send-a-sign-out-request:

> When you wish to sign the user out of the app, it is not sufficient to
>   clear your app's cookies or otherwise end the session with the user.
>   You must also redirect the user to the end_session_endpoint for
>   sign-out. If you fail to do so, the user will be able to
>   reauthenticate to your app without entering their credentials again,
>   because they will have a valid single sign-on session with the Azure
>   AD endpoint.

So, my question is pretty straightforward: if the application has cleared all local state, then when the application besides to sign back in, what will tell Azure AD that there's a valid single sign-on session?  There's no cookie there, and you're not sending anything in the URL to indicate a sign-in session, so what's Azure AD using to determine this, in the quoted scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the SSO cookie of the Azure AD itself.

If you take a closer look at [the application models for Azure AD integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-app-types), you will notice that every authentication request goes to an authorization endpoint in the `https://login.microsoftonline/[tenant_id|common]/`.. endpoint. This endpoint maintains SSO session with the user agent. Even if you sign-out of a single applicaiton, that SSO at Azure AD is still kept. That's why when your application later redirects the user to sign-in, he/she is already signed-in and do not get prompted.

This is very well described in a "hidden" part of the documentation about a deprecated featre - [Configurable Token lifetimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes). Check the [Single sign-on session tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#single-sign-on-session-tokens) part. Although, the feature (Configurable token lifetimes) per se is **depricated** and will be **retired** at some point in time, the Single sign-on session token is how Azure AD works and this is something that is not changes or affected. I hope that part of the documentation will find its place once the token lifetime feature is retired.

Comment: Where is that cookie coming from if the application has cleared all the cookies?

Comment: bybthe way it has nothing to do with PRT, which is totally another topic anyway. It has only to do with SSO cookies on login.microsoftonline.com domain. which your web app can't delete anyway.

Comment: astaykov and I had a conversation offline about this and I saw where my disconnect was. The documentation I linked to is around web applications, which means the target app can't clear the master AAD cookie because it's in a different domain. In a native app, which isn't what the docs are referring to, you might clear all context and have that work without a sign out. I conflated the two scenarios when thinking about this